# How to display an Image from Google Drive in an html email?

Tags: html, html-email

I'm making a html leter right now, and the image I'm trying to display doesn't appear when I'm receiving it. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600px" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1QJk7MIu-1hriNSyf1k71YyGwtQBqjy02" alt="Demo_image" srcset="">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

So, when I was viewing this page in a browser it looked fine (if it's okay to say so about html mailing), it also looked fine when I was sending it via Outlook, but the letter I received in gmail simply didn't have this image and was empty.

Comment: Your image behind your link `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1QJk7MIu-1hriNSyf1k71YyGwtQBqjy02` is an SVG, may it is not handled as an image in gmail

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive is not built for hosting images publicly, AFAIK. You may need to use an image host specifically designed for it.

However, you could try the following:

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1QJk7MIu-1hriNSyf1k71YyGwtQBqjy02" alt="Demo_image" width="600">
```

I've removed the blank srcset, which might be interfering. I've also added a width, which is normally added to the img tag.